# convert code (remove dagger)

Tags: java, android, mvvm, kotlin, dagger-2

Could anyone help me to remove Dagger annotation and create object manually
When I am using dagger2 and I have this code

```
@Inject
ViewModelProvider.Factory mViewModelFactory; 

@Override
    public BlogViewModel getViewModel() {
        mBlogViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, mViewModelFactory).get(BlogViewModel.class);
        return mBlogViewModel;
    }
```

I am trying to convert it Kotlin and use manual init
How could I create mViewModelFactory here?

```
viewModelFactory = BlogViewModel.Factory(getViewModel().dataManager,getViewModel().schedulerProvider)
```

I have crash on this line

```
mBlogViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, mViewModelFactory).get(BlogViewModel.class)
```

Comment: `remove Dagger annotation and create object manually` that seems very counter-intuitive to me if you're using dependency injection library

Comment: show your log and explain in detail what you want?

Comment: @HassanUsman I want init both objects viewmodel and viewmodelfactory but they have reference to each other which brings to crash.